# Javascript search title through all list not working

Tags: javascript, html, search

I made some search function for my website. I already finish my keyword search successfully. Now, I am trying to search title from my list. I already tried a few from Google, but none of them works for me.

My search should works with keyword and any data attribute. Example : When I search Apple , the result should display number 1 and Apple. If I search for 1, the result should display 1 and add apple.

Here is my search function :

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;

    input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
    title = document.querySelectorAll("[title=" + CSS.escape(input) + "]");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("result");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="result">
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="myCase" ">Case Sensitive</label>
</div>

<ul>
    <li>
        <div>Search 1</div>
        <ul>
            <li title="Apple">1</li>
            <li title="Ball">2</li>
            <li title="Cat">3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Search 2</div>
        <ul>
            <li title="Eagle">4</li>
            <li title="Ferry">5</li>
            <li title="Glue">36</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made a snippet from your code, it seems to be working. What's wrong? You just say "none of them works".

Comment: Except `36/li>` that's not properly closed, this can be an issue.

Comment: Example I want to search Apple so the result should display only number 1. It will grab data-attribute from number 1 that = Apple

Comment: Ah. In that case you shouldn't filter by `innerHTML` but by `attributes.title`, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Probably just check for the title:

```
var filter = "CAT";
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")
 .forEach(function(el){
   el.style.display =
     el.attributes.title.toUpperCase().includes(filter)
     ?"block"
     :"none";
 });
```